# Render Alert component in singleton class

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have singleton class that handles all server request of my app.
My issue is to show Alert from this singleton if there is connection issues during internet connection. 
So far I try to show Alert in this way:

```
ReactDom.render(Alert.alert(
   'Alert title',
   'Alert message'
));
```

This one shows an Alert on app screen but after one second shown red screen with message: ReactDom.render(): Invalid component element.

So, how can i show an Alert on screen without this error message?

Comment: ReactDom is not available on mobile. There is no Document Object Model in react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Oh..For newbies like me..
If you want to show Alert inside class that not expands Component just write:

```
Alert.alert('alert title', 'alert message');
```

and it works!